# Can expect spawn a bash function?

Tags: linux, bash, function, tcl, expect

Here is a very simplified example:

```
# expect -c "spawn socat -v -,raw,echo=0,nonblock /dev/ttyS0; interact"
```

`expect` executes an in-line script, which spawns `socat` in order to connect to a `serial` device. But what if we have a `bash` function called serial (which is quite handy):

```
# serial(){ socat -v -,raw,echo=0,nonblock /dev/ttyS0;}
# expect -c "spawn serial; interact"
spawn serial
couldn't execute "serial": no such file or directory
    while executing
"spawn serial"
```

Is it possible to force `expect` to execute a function, without a wrapper script or binary?

Comment: I don't think so. Bash functions are interpreted and run by `bash`, so bash has to be invoked to execute them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a bash function or builtin inside `spawn`, you have to make the spawn be of a bash subprocess that runs the function or builtin. This is done via the `-c` option to bash, which lets you give a little inline script for bash to run.

```
spawn bash -c "serial"
```

Remember that the *single* argument after `-c` is the inline script to run. Arguments after that get assigned to bash's positional parameters.

Comment: As soon as  [bishop](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2908724/bishop) said functions are being interpreted by bash, I tried to `spawn bash -c function` but I was struggling with passing arguments to it, so thanks for the quote tip!

Comment: and don't forget to export the function so the spawned bash can see it.

Answer (score 2):

You can `export` the shell function so a new `spawn`ed shell can call it. For example:

```
% cat foo.sh
the_func()
{
    echo hello world
}
export -f the_func

expect -c "spawn bash -c the_func; interact"
% bash foo.sh
spawn bash -c the_func
hello world
%
```